# What's is the correct way of adding new nodes to a Clickhouse cluster?

Tags: clickhouse

Currently we are running CH at version 20.4.8.99.
We have 3 nodes filled with ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree tables.

What's the correct procedure of adding additional nodes? Internet is filled with info about setting up a cluster but not so much on expending it (failed to find any info in docs too).

I've tried simply creating new tables with the DDL from the existing nodes, but only got quite a few errors. Mainly about node having an existing data directory for a table (as if table was detached at some point).

`ATTACH` also results in syntax warning:

`ATTACH TABLE table FROM 'path' (columns types) engine = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree(...)`

result:

`Syntax error: failed at position 34 ... Expected one of: storage definition, ENGINE (version 20.4.8.99 (official build))`

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the same CREATE TABLE on each new node. CREATE TABLE -- creates a new replica/shard.

You can get ATTACH TABLE from the existing node and replace ATTACH with CREATE and execute the CREATE TABLE command.

There are a new **DATABASE** engine -- Replicated which can mitigate this. Using ReplicatedDatabase you need to simply add new node to the cluster. And ReplicatedDatabase will create tables automagically. Altinity Operator (if you use K8s) does the same magic.

20.4 -- is out of support. Try to upgrade at least to 20.8 (though it also almost EOL).